# Server side projection

Tags: c#, mongodb

im using c# mongodb driver. in its official documentation about **Lambda Expressions Projection** they say:

> The driver supports using expression trees to render projections.
>   Inherently, a lambda expression contains all the information necessary to form both the projection on the server as well as the client-side result and requires no further information.

and some lines after that, we have:

> When a Find projection is defined using a lambda expression, it is run client-side.

now i'm a bit confused about **Lambda Expression** projection side. is it running server-side or client-side?

when i project a document using `.Include()` and `.Exclude()` methods, is it creating a server-side projection or a client-side one?
for example if i filter a `Post` document and i want to exclude its `tags` field with `.Exclude()` method, does the driver fetch the whole document and then exclude `tags` field in the application or it issues a Mongodb `find()` request with `{ tags: 0 }` projection?

what is the difference between **Lambda Expression** projection and projecting documents using `.Include()` and `.Exclude()` when i want to find and project some documents in the aspect of projection side?

thanks.

Comment: documentation link: [lambda expression](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/definitions/#lambda-expressions) - [Find Projection](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/definitions/#find)

Comment: You do not need to, and shouldn't put [tags in your question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). The tagging system is more than adequate (the little blue things at the bottom of your question). Also see the help on [tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title." (it includes a list of formats you shouldn't use if you include tags in your title, which includes [tag] [question title])

Comment: You're welcome :-) I hadn't considered your question so I'm interested to know what the answer is.

Comment: it is somehow funny if it performs projection in the client-side, but the documentation is confusing, i think.

Comment: I get the impression it might mean that the server returns only the fields in the expression, and then it's projected to the new form client-side.

Comment: me too, and it should be like that. there must be some mapping process to map server-returned bson document to c# model, but documentation says "lambda expression" projection is different from normal `.Exclude()` and `.Include()` form. i want to know which one is delegating projection to the mongodb server and which one is excluding received document fields in the application.

Comment: ive found the answer, @John! and [here](https://twitter.com/xeptore/status/1030888847381590022) is its tweet! thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some research and examining both types of **projection** on a sample database with enabled ***full detailed profiling***, i've found that both `.Exclude()` and `.Include()` (using `Projection Builder`), and single **Expression** projection types run on the server-side. i still dont know what is the difference between theses projection - as the official documentation says, but i solved my question and now im sure that main projection part is done on the server-side.

here are results of my researches in two different types of driver-provided projections (using `hte` example database and just useful parts of profiling results shown):

Projection using **Expression**:
[image: Projection using **Expression**]

Projection using **Projection Builders (`.Include()` `.Exclude()`)**:
[image: Projection using **Projection Builders (<code>.Include()</code> <code>.Exclude()</code>)**]

---

it seems i can just use **links** to pictures for now (lack of *reputation*!).
links to helpful docs that i've used are available in comments.
i hope this helps.

Comment: also thanks to Mr. @[John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) for his help to improve my *first* question

Comment: driver projection official docs: [Projection](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/reading/#projections) - [Projection Definition Builders](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/reading/#projection-definition-builder) - [Projection using lambda expressions](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/reading/#lambda-expressions)

Comment: mongodb database profiling: [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)

Comment: I'm glad you managed to find an answer :) I've edited your post so that the images are now part of your answer.